# A linear programming question, no feasible solution question

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying for a test and I came across this question:
Let $a_1, a_2, . . . a_m \in \Bbb R^n$
such that $m > n+1$. Assume that for the set of m inequalities $a_i^t x ≤ b_i$
there is no feasible solution. Prove that there are $n + 1$ inequalities out of the $m$ which are not feasible.

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: $m>n+1$ or $m \geq n+1$ ?

Comment: m $> n+1$ I'm also confused about why the strict inequality is required